# Can I analyze Video in AI?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

For those who do AI or Machine Learning, is it possible to analyze video? For example, here’s a tidbit from an article I’ve been reading:

> in basketball, data can help coaches determine if a player executed a jump shot well because he was skilled, the pass was good or the defense was bad. If he is skilled, he can be used to lead key strategies. If the pass is good, it identifies players that work well together and use them for the same. If the defense is bad, coaches can strategize plays that take advantage of this weakness.

How would I measure this with AI? I’d like to find the true value of a high school player and how they’d affect their college team.

Comment: Yes, it is, but your problem is complicated, esp. for a beginner. It would be easier to start without the video, and address the second part of your question based on readily-available statistics like the score and roster for several games. With this baseline, you can begin to incorporate visual features. I would start with human recognition to determine who attempted to pass to whom. Only then would I worry about analyzing things like posture, and gait. [Here is a relevant survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5c4c/e36063dd3496a5926afd301e562899ff53ea.pdf). Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you @Emre. Is it called Computer Vision? I found this class on Udacity https://www.udacity.com/course/introduction-to-computer-vision--ud810

Comment: Yes, broadly speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, especially using Deep learning.
To get an idea, you can see this github project: 
 https://github.com/HuaizhengZhang/Awsome-Deep-Learning-for-Video-Analysis